# Leak inside android function 'setTextColor'

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I have developed Button with stroke text

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Join;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ButtonStrokeText extends Button
{
    private int strokeColor=Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private int strokeWidth=2;

    public ButtonStrokeText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
    public ButtonStrokeText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.ButtonStrokeText);
        strokeColor=a.getColor(R.styleable.ButtonStrokeText_textStrokeColor, strokeColor);
        strokeWidth=a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStrokeText_textStrokeWidth, strokeWidth);
        a.recycle();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        final ColorStateList textColor = getTextColors();

        TextPaint paint = getPaint();

        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeMiter(10);
        setTextColor(strokeColor);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        setTextColor(textColor);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

But there is leak inside setTextColor(strokeColor). If i comment this line activity not leaked, otherwise i have leak.

My question is, how can i avoid this leak?

Comment: Please post logcat output

Comment: Please show the code for setTextColor()

Comment: setTextColor is android functionn from TextView http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setTextColor(int)

Comment: logcat show nothing. I check leak via MAT and using my class http://pastebin.com/f1YvDZUr . I just save context and see it after release(reference counter)

Comment: You're extending Button. Button does not have a setTextColor() method.  I don't see how this code will compile.

Comment: Android Button class extends TextView

Comment: Ah, doh!  Sorry.  You're right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this leak using.

```
@Override
public void invalidate()
{
}
```

Maybe it is wrong, but it is working)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is when you instantiate your `ButtonStrokeText`. Use `getApplicationContext()` in your calls instead of `this` (Activity Context). I can see `strokeColor` refer to `a` and `a` refers to the `context`. Activity contexts can cause leaks, so use Application contexts intead.

Comment: Try replacing all uses of `TypedArray a` to fixed colors to see if you still get the leak as this is the most suspected.